# React js alinear Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jxl

tengo rato tratando de enviar al final del item a un button, aqui un impr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que el botton este a la derecha del iten de borde verde, aqui el codigo:

```
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">          
        <header className="App-header">
          <div className="App-header-company">
            <img className="App-logo" src={logo}  alt="logo" />
            <div className="App-header-title" style={{ marginTop:'auto', padding: '10px', }}>My App News</div>
          </div>          
          <div className="App-header-btnMenu"> <MenuButton /> </div>
        </header>
        <div className="content">                      
          <Nav/> 
                   
        </div>      
      </div>
    );
  }

.App {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.App-header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 380px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  background-color: #282c34;
  color: white; 
}

.App-header-company{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; 
  border: solid 4px yellow;
}

.App-header-btnMenu{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;  
  border: solid 4px green;
}
```

MenuButton.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const MenuButtonWrapper = styled.button`

display: none; 
position: relative;

  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    display:flex;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgb(50, 50, 50);
    margin: auto;
  }
`

function MenuButton() {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    const handleClick = () => {
      setOpen(!open)
    }

  return !open ? (
    <MenuButtonWrapper onClick={handleClick}>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 80" width="30" height="30" fill="#282c34">
        <rect width="90" height="10" />
        <rect y="30" width="80" height="10" />
        <rect y="60" width="70" height="10" />
      </svg>
    </MenuButtonWrapper>
  ) : (
    <MenuButtonWrapper onClick={handleClick}>
      <svg
        className="svg-icon"
        width="30"
        height="30"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        fill="#282c34"
      > 
        <path d="M15.898,4.045c-0.271-0.272-0.713-0.272-0.986,0l-4.71,4.711L5.493,4.045c-0.272-0.272-0.714-0.272-0.986,0s-0.272,0.714,0,0.986l4.709,4.711l-4.71,4.711c-0.272,0.271-0.272,0.713,0,0.986c0.136,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.492,0.203c0.179,0,0.357-0.067,0.493-0.203l4.711-4.711l4.71,4.711c0.137,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.494,0.203c0.178,0,0.355-0.067,0.492-0.203c0.273-0.273,0.273-0.715,0-0.986l-4.711-4.711l4.711-4.711C16.172,4.759,16.172,4.317,15.898,4.045z" />
      </svg>
    </MenuButtonWrapper>
  )
}

export default MenuButton;
```

en  Menu button, la intencion es que al clickear se muestre nav y se oculte.

como pueden ver, se trata de un header(el contenedor) y el mismo lo divido por la mitad, en donde el item de border amarrillo es uno y el verde es el otro, dentro del borde verde tengo el botton que es un componente aparte, a este botton quiero que este al final del item de borde verde, en que me estoy equivocando??

Comment: Puedes compartir el código del componente `MenuButon`? Así como presentas el código no hay ningún problema con los estilos, puede ser que el problema venga del `MenuButton`

Comment: listo!! le acabo de añadir float: right; a menubutton crei que me iba a funcionar.. pero no funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del componente `MenuButton`, descarta las siguientes propiedades del styled component :

```
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
```

Debe quedar así:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    display:flex;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgb(50, 50, 50);
  }
```

Otra observación que puede ser de ayuda, en el `return` dentro del contexto boolean del operador condicional, en la primera expresión, falta la clase para `svg`:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 80" width="30" height="30" fill="#282c34">
```

Parece que debe ir así:

```
<svg className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 80" width="30" height="30" fill="#282c34">
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: g.4! mil gracias por tu aporte, si me sirvió de mucho!!

Comment: Que bien colega, no olvides votar y aceptar la respuesta si consideras que fue de utilidad, saludos

Comment: listo (Y) mil gracias!